# Convert dt/dd list into a li list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to convert a list of product details from dt/dd html format into li?

for example:

```
 <dt class="float-left"> Composition</dt>
 <dd>Suede 100%</dd>
 <dt class="float-left">Lining Composition</dt>
 <dd>Suede 100%</dd>
```

into:

```
<li> Composition: Suede 100%</li>
<li> Lining Composition: Suede 100%</li>
```

I tried doing this numerous, but don't know where to start?

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nj0h4ddh/

Comment: What is your approach so far?

Comment: This kind of amendment would be better achieved by simply re-writing the source HTML. Assuming that's not possible, select each `dt` element, grab it's text along with the `next('dd')` and append a new `li` element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)/[`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) methods:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4pdjdb9h/)

```
$('.product-detail-dl').wrapInner('<ul></ul>')
    .find('ul').unwrap()
    .find('dt, dd').wrapInner('<li></li>')
    .find('li').unwrap();
```

Input:

```
<dl class="product-detail-dl">
  <dt class="float-left"> Composition</dt>
  <dd>Suede 100%</dd>
  <dt class="float-left">Lining Composition</dt>
  <dd>Suede 100%</dd>
</dl>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
  <li>Composition</li>
  <li>Suede 100%</li>
  <li>Lining Composition</li>
  <li>Suede 100%</li>
</ul>
```

---

In order to combine the `dt`/`dd` elements, you could use the following before wrapping/upwrapping the elements:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pdwqhj8p/)

```
$('.product-detail-dl dd').each(function () {
    $(this).prev().append(': ' + this.innerText);
}).remove();
```

Input:

```
<dl class="product-detail-dl">
  <dt class="float-left"> Composition</dt>
  <dd>Suede 100%</dd>
  <dt class="float-left">Lining Composition</dt>
  <dd>Suede 100%</dd>
  <dt class="float-left">Sole Composition</dt>
  <dd>Rubber 100%</dd>
  <dt class="float-left">Brand Style ID</dt>
  <dd>333824045</dd>
</dl>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
  <li>Composition: Suede 100%</li>
  <li>Lining Composition: Suede 100%</li>
  <li>Sole Composition: Rubber 100%</li>
  <li>Brand Style ID: 333824045</li>
</ul>
```

---

As a side note, you could also use the [`.replaceWith()` method](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) for the same results:

```
$('.product-detail-dl dd').each(function () {
    $(this).prev().append(': ' + this.innerText);
}).remove();

$('.product-detail-dl').find('dt, dd').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>');
});
$('.product-detail-dl').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<ul>' + this.innerHTML + '</ul>');
});
```

Comment: doesn't match expected output

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there may be more than a one to one relationship of `<dt>` to `<dd>` you can use `nextUntil()` and `replaceWith()` to create new structure:

```
var $dl = $('.product-detail-dl'),
    $ul = $('<ul>');
// loop over all the `<dt>`
$dl.find('dt').each(function () {
    var $dt = $(this),
        title = $dt.text();
        // loop over following siblings until another `<dt>` is reached
        $dt.nextUntil('dt').each(function () {
            $ul.append('<li>' + title + ': ' + $(this).text() + '</li>')
        });
});
// replace original list
$dl.replaceWith($ul)
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nj0h4ddh/3/)**</kbd>

References

- [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)
- [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpLPvx

```
 <dt class="float-left"> Composition</dt>
 <dd>Suede 100%</dd>
 <dt class="float-left">Lining Composition</dt>
 <dd>Suede 100%</dd>
```

Jquery

```
$('dt').each(function(){
    var child = $(this).next('dd');
    $(this).replaceWith( "<li>" + $( this ).html()+' '+ child.html() + "</li>" );
    child.remove();
})
```

Comment: Would perform better if you cache `$(this)`.